# Signalr SQL scaleout : drawbacks of using multiple streams?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-backplane

In the [SignalR Performance](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance) page, we can read :

> A Stream in this context is a scale unit used by the scaleout
>   provider; this is a table if SQL Server is used, a Topic if Service
>   Bus is used, and a Subscription if Redis is used. Each stream ensures
>   ordered read and write operations; a **single stream is a potential
>   scale bottleneck**, so the number of streams can be increased to help
>   reduce that bottleneck. If multiple streams are used, SignalR will
>   automatically distribute (shard) messages across these streams in a
>   way that ensures messages sent from any given connection are in order.

The stream count (ie. table in SQL) can be set like this :

```
var connectionString = "(your connection string)";
var config = new SqlScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString) { 
    TableCount = 3,
    MaxQueueLength = 50 };
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(config);
```

But the `TableCount` is 1 by default in SQL scaleout. If this is a scale bottleneck, why is it 1 by default ? What if I set it to 50 ?

The documentation doesn't give any clue to decide which value to give. Should I set it to 1, 3, 10, 1000 ? **What are pros and cons of a big value ?** Does it just increase latency ?

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.sqlscaleoutconfiguration(v=vs.118).aspx

> TableCount
>   Gets or sets the number of tables to store messages in.
>   Using more tables reduces lock contention and may increase throughput.
>   This must be consistent between all nodes in the web farm. Defaults to 1.